# Batch file - "If" command with range

Tags: batch-file

Here is the issue. I've been developing some things on batch and use the `if` command frequently. I've been wanting to have it so that if a variable is equal to a number within a range, then continue the command. This is an example of what I've been doing:

```
:EXAMPLE
If %variable1% LSS 100 goto fun1
If %variable2% GEQ 100 goto fun2
Echo filler. 
Pause

:fun1
Echo filler
Pause

:fun2
If %variable2% GEQ 900 goto fun3
Echo filler
Pause

:fun3
Echo filler
Pause
```

It works just fine, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to do so like `if %variable% == 100-899 goto fun3`.

I'm not sure it exists but if you have a solution please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `If %Something% lss 20 If %something% geq 10 echo 10 to 19`

Comment: Your question text does not match your question code. You stated `if %variable% == 100-899 goto fun3`, but clearly in your code `:fun3` is for `900+`, and `:fun2` is for `100-899`, but even those appear to be for variables defined as `%variable2%` not as `%variable%`.

Comment: just sort your `if`s descending: `if %var% geq 900 goto fun3`, `if %var% geq 100 goto fun2`, `goto fun1`

Comment: Try seeing `for /l`. It can accomplish this for you

Comment: @Compo yes it does, it does work. If it is between 100 and 900 (so 1-899) then that strand of code would continue in fun2. But if it is 900 or above then it goes to fun 3.

Comment: @VictorChavez, you should read your question and my comment again. There is no `%variable%` in your code, only a `%variable1%` and a `%variable2%`. You've not provided us with any way of understanding your task or how `%variable%` correlates with it, or the other two variables. Currently, you'll always be prompted with the first `Pause`, unless `%variable1% < 100` or `%variable2% ≥ 100`. You'll always be prompted with the second `Pause`, unless `%variable2% ≥ 100`. You'll always be prompted with the third `Pause`, unless `%variable2% ≥ 900`. You'll always be prompted with the fourth `Pause`.

Comment: @Compo ohh well this is just an example, I didn't want to add my actual code since I'm at 35k lines of code atm... I didn't bother to add in everything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user12431753 had touched upon, I have found that

```
if %variable1% GEQ 300 (if %variable1% LSS 899 echo Hi)
```

is the most effective way to set a range.